# Create subfolders bases on image labels in csv

Tags: python, pandas, image, directory, label

I want to create subfolders with related images for each class. Now, I only have a folder with all images. I created a .csv with images_id and labels. I was able to create the subfolders based on the labels but I cant move the images in the related subfolders.

My folder structure looks likes that:

- data (images)

  - img1.jpg
  - img2.jpg
  - ...jpg
- labels.csv (image_id, label)
- notebook.ipynb

```
import shutil, os
import pandas as pd

labels = pd.read_csv("labels.csv")
labels = labels.sort_values('Manu_Series_Year')

class_names = list(labels.Manu_Series_Year.unique())

train_images = 'train'
train_cat = 'train_'

#creating subfolders
for i in class_names:
    os.makedirs(os.path.join('train_', i))

#moving the image files to their respective categories
for c in class_names: # Category Name
    for i in list(labels[labels['Manu_Series_Year']==c]['Image_id']): # Image Id
        get_image = os.path.join('train', str(i)) # Path to Images 
        move_image_to_cat = shutil.move(get_image, 'train_/'+c)
```

```
Traceback 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.2032.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\shutil.py in move(src, dst, copy_function)
    813     try:
--> 814         os.rename(src, real_dst)
    815     except OSError:

FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] Das System kann den angegebenen Pfad nicht finden: 'C://Users/deniz/OneDrive/MA/Dataset/archive_unbekannt/train\\1' -> 'C://Users/deniz/OneDrive/MA/Dataset/archive_unbekannt/train_/Acura ILX 2013'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-28-8d99c8eb764e> in <module>
     18     for i in list(labels[labels['Manu_Series_Year']==c]['Image_id']): # Image Id
     19         get_image = os.path.join('C://Users/deniz/OneDrive/MA/Dataset/archive_unbekannt/train', str(i)) # Path to Images
---> 20         move_image_to_cat = shutil.move(get_image, 'C://Users/deniz/OneDrive/MA/Dataset/archive_unbekannt/train_/'+c)

C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.2032.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\shutil.py in move(src, dst, copy_function)
    832             rmtree(src)
    833         else:
--> 834             copy_function(src, real_dst)
    835             os.unlink(src)
    836     return real_dst

C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.2032.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\shutil.py in copy2(src, dst, follow_symlinks)
    441     if os.path.isdir(dst):
    442         dst = os.path.join(dst, os.path.basename(src))
--> 443     copyfile(src, dst, follow_symlinks=follow_symlinks)
    444     copystat(src, dst, follow_symlinks=follow_symlinks)
    445     return dst

C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.2032.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\shutil.py in copyfile(src, dst, follow_symlinks)
    263     else:
    264         try:
--> 265             with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc, open(dst, 'wb') as fdst:
    266                 # macOS
    267                 if _HAS_FCOPYFILE:

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'train\\1'
```

UPDATE

```
import shutil, os
import pandas as pd

labels = pd.read_csv("labels.csv")
labels = labels.sort_values('Manu_Series_Year')

class_names = list(labels.Manu_Series_Year.unique())

train_images = 'data'
train_cat = 'data_'

#creating subfolders
for c in class_names:
    dest = 'data_' + c
    os.makedirs(c)
    for i in list(labels[labels['Manu_Series_Year']==c]['Image_id']): # Image Id
        get_image = os.path.join('data', str(i)) # Path to Images 
        move_image_to_cat = shutil.move(get_image, dest)
```

UPDATE2

```
# should go in the right direction
# works
import shutil, os
import pandas as pd

# read label
labels = pd.read_csv("labels.csv")
# sort label
labels = labels.sort_values('Manu_Series_Year')

# take unique labels
class_names = list(labels.Manu_Series_Year.unique())

# loc of train data
train_images = 'data'
# loc of labels with img
train_cat = 'data_'

#creating subfolders
for c in class_names:
    dest = 'data_/' + c
    os.makedirs(dest)
    for i in list(labels[labels['Manu_Series_Year']==c]['Image_id']): # Image Id
        get_image = os.path.join('data', i) # Path to Images 
        move_image_to_cat = shutil.move(get_image, dest)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it's this part:

```
#creating subfolders
for i in class_names:
    os.makedirs(os.path.join('train_', i))
```

that creates folders like `root/train_/[class_name]`

then you try to move your images with:

```
move_image_to_cat = shutil.move(get_image, 'train_/'+c)
```

### Suggestions

- Just do one single loop over your class names (you're looping twice)
- Store the destination path to a variable

Code:

```
#creating subfolders
for c in class_names:
    dest = 'train_' + c
    os.makedirs(dest)
    for i in list(labels[labels['Manu_Series_Year']==c]['Image_id']): # Image Id
        get_image = os.path.join('data', i) # Path to Images 
        move_image_to_cat = shutil.move(get_image, dest)
```

Comment: Thank you but unfortuantly it doesnt work and i get the same error. Its strange because the error shows the id train/1 (id) and not the class. Do you know what I mean?

Comment: Well then you need to update the file path so it reflects the path to the image: `get_image = os.path.join('train', "img"+str(i)+".jpg")`, something like that?

Comment: yes but didnt work either

Comment: Where are your images? In a "data" folder or a "train" folder? Please paste the path to an actual image and show us the content of the CSV so we can understand your logic.

Comment: I restructured my folder to make it easier. my data are here D:\Git\image-recognition\data. the .csv called labels.csv consists of two columns (Manu_Seires_Year (that's that label) and image_id (image_id.jpg))

Comment: Like I said: "Please paste the path to an actual image"

Comment: D:\Git\image-recognition\data\Bentley_Bentayga_2017_229_21_600_60_12_78_68_202_12_AWD_5_4_SUV_APo.jpg

Comment: class for that image looks like Bentley Bentayaga 2017

Comment: Then `get_image = os.path.join('data', i)`?

Comment: I updated my code in the description. Now the files move out of the data direction but not into data_ folder (which doesn't exist anymore. i don't know why) and not in jpg format